# Matrix multiplication of a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix, for instance, `A = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])` and ndarray of the form `B = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])`. I want a matrix multiplication of each array of the array `B` by the matrix `A`.

I did a for cycle, like this

```
C = []
for b in B:
    C.append(np.matmul(A,b))
C=np.array(C)
```

out[]:

```
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6]])
```

But I know that this for cycle is time consuming. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do funny things with matrix multiplication dimensions, [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can help clarify what's going on.

```
In [40]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',A,B)
Out[40]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Here we are doing the sum-of-products on the `j` dimension, and putting `B's` first dimension first in the result.  Ordinary matmul would be `ij,jk->ik`.  From that we can see the need for the two transposes in the other answer.

```
(A@B.T).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: First of all you can use normal matrix multiplication and transposing for that. And 2ndly you can use `@` to ask for a matrix multiplication in python.

So try

```
(A@B.T).T
```

or equivalently

```
(B@A.T)
```